# Data type ArrayType(FloatType,false) is not supported -collaborative filtering

Tags: pyspark, filtering, k-means, recommendation-engine, collaborative

I'm learning about recommendation system,
I want to pass the userFactor and itemFactor created in ALS model to the K-means, but k-means want VectorUDT but i got ArrayType(FloatType) from the model.

I'm also trying to pass userFactor to vector assembler and then created a vector to k-means but same error arise help.

new at this.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler


userFactorsDF= alsmodel.userFactors.select("features")

vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["features"], outputCol="features")
featuresdf = vecAssembler.transform(userFactorsDF)

kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
model1 = kmeans.fit(featuresdf)


ERROR

IllegalArgumentException: u'Data type ArrayType(FloatType,false) is not supported.'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-05324b5cde72> in <module>()
      7 vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["features"], outputCol="features")
      8 
----> 9 featuresdf = vecAssembler.transform(userFactorsDF)
     10 
     11 kmeans = KMeans().setK(2).setSeed(1)
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -1):

you may try Writing a UDF and extract values from that before passing it to VectorAssembler.

```
UserDefinedFunction mode = udf((Seq<String> array, fromIndex int, toIndex int) -> array.slice(fromIndex ,toIndex ).mkString(","));
```